# Add "In:" before editor in custom bst file

Tags: bibliographies, custom-bib

I have a custom .bst file (created from makebst). What is the syntax to add "In: " before editor?

Here's an excerpt from my file (note: I'm very new to this and fudged the code to display editor with author, as opposed to only displaying editor with no author... if there's a better way to do this please advise):

```
FUNCTION {inbook}
{ output.bibitem
  author empty$
    { format.editors "author and editor" output.check
      editor format.key output
    }
    { format.authors output.nonnull
      crossref missing$
        { "author and editor" editor either.or.check }
        'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
  format.authors
  format.date "year" output.check
  date.block
  format.chapter.pages "chapter and pages" output.check
  new.sentence
  format.editors "author and editor" output.check
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  crossref missing$
    {
      format.bvolume output
      new.block
      format.number.series output
      format.edition output
      new.sentence
      format.publisher.address output
    }
    {
      format.chapter.pages "chapter and pages" output.check
      new.block
      format.book.crossref output.nonnull
    }
  if$
  crossref missing$
    { format.isbn output }
    'skip$
  if$
  format.pages "pages" output.check
  format.doi output
  new.block
  format.url output
  new.block
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}
```

Comment: How is the `format.editors` function defined in the bst file?

Comment: `FUNCTION {format.editors}
{ editor "editor" format.names duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      "," *
      " " *
      get.bbl.editor
      *
    }
  if$
}`

Comment: Have you tried replacing `","` with `", In: "`?

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the formatted code of the `format.editors` function in the body of your query. For sure, it would be easier to read...